# Shrink/Fatten not working; due to parallel vertices/handles?

Tags: bezier-curves, hair

Alt+S for Shrink/Fatten doesn't work for me on these bezier curves, and I think the problem is that all the vertices/handles are parallel to the curve length. How do I fix this? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can't use both a Taper Curve *and* Control-Point Radius (which <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> adjusts,) to control the scale of a curve's bevel. You have to choose one or the other.

Comment: I admit I know very little about the fine details of curves, but I made another hair with nurbs curves and was able to get decent curved shapes and also shrink/fatten segments. (I think I also had colliding edge rings at one point though, which bezier doesn't appear to have.) Is there a preference between one or the other for hair?

Comment: Ahhh! .. In that case, I'm no wiser than you.. I've never tried this with NURBS . A quick test shows the same result though.. you don't seem to be able to use a Taper Object _and_ radius. If you use a Taper Object, that's in charge. and Alt S has no effect.